# prompt user to confirm to submit without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I have a submit event that use `native POST` (non-ajax).

```
<form method="post">
<button type="submit" value="submit"></button>
</form>
```

How can I prompt the user when the user clicked on the submit button? if the user clicked confirm, then only it will continue.. I know I can do this with ajax, but is it possible to do it with the `native post` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `confirm()` to the `submit` event of the form, and return its value to the anonymous function as follows (using jQuery):

```
$('form').on('submit', function() { 
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tazuj6o4/)

Comment: can I it inline? since it's just one line

Comment: Well you *can* inline, but that's very bad practice. (See the comment I've just made on the other answer).

Comment: why bad practice? for my register page i don't have any js file. so might as well just line, it's just to prompt a one line confirmation message.

Comment: @MariaJane, did you read the link I sent across? https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
```

Comment: Try to avoid recommending intrusive event handlers.

Comment: @BenM I found this is more straight forward, why not?

Comment: @MariaJane https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: @MariaJane because they're outdated, make the code more difficult to maintain (which is vital when working in a team) and also violate the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle

Comment: I don;t care about principle, it's just a simple application.

Comment: @MariaJane What a great outlook to have, that's sure to make you an excellent developer.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the recommended way but it will do what you want

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit');">
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function submitForm() {
var r = confirm("Do you want to submit the form?");
if (r == true) {
    document.getElementById("mainForm").submit();
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="mainForm" method="post" onsubmit="submitForm()">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't recommend intrusive event handlers. Also, there's no need for your `if() else` block, just `return` the `confirm()` function.

Comment: Its to show there are possibility to get a response from the confirmation dialog, most of cases you need to do something when submit or cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
<form id="f" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return false">
  Enter name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" onclick="t()" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
function t() {
    if(confirm("Yo")){
       var form = document.getElementById("f")

       form.submit()

    }
}
</script>
```